# configure Heartbeat on Centos Linux - error message

Tags: linux, centos, heartbeat, heartbeat1

I installed Heartbeat on my Centos Linux and it seems to partially work..but
I'm trying to monitor a service with no success. only when I reboot the main server the backup server takes over.
in the logs I get :

```
heartbeat[30476]: 2012/03/20_18:51:57 WARN: string2msg_ll: node [node1] failed authentication
heartbeat[30476]: 2012/03/20_18:51:58 WARN: string2msg_ll: node [node02] failed authentication
```

the authkeys is identical (copied from one to another).
this is my ha.cf:

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
logfacility local0
keepalive 2
deadtime 30
initdead 120
bcast eth0
udpport 694
auto_failback on
node server01.com 
node server02.com
```

haresources :

```
server01.com 38.108.117.3 aim chat
```

any idea how to fix the problem so if a service stops the other server take over
Thanks!
E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the heartbeat v1 syntax. If you use that here will be no monitoring (per default). If you want monitoring as well you will have to convert to v2 syntax (XML) and will have to add monitoring methods.

Some other notes about your configuration:

- Auto-failback is never a good idea. You can create a nice "ping pong" with that
- Broadcasting in not a good idea with just two nodes. Use ucast instead.
- Just a single network connection? Have fun with lots of split-brains.

Now back to your initial question: This looks as if other nodes (from different clusters?) try to communicate on the same broadcast-IP and the same UDP-port.

"Your" nodes are "server01.com" and "server02.com" - you see two other nodes ("node1" and "node02").

- Use different UDP-ports for every cluster
- Use unicast instead of broadcast (see above).

Update: How to configure unicast:

RTFM (read the **fine** manual) from `rpm -qd|grep "ha.cf"`:

```
#       Set up a unicast / udp heartbeat medium
#       ucast [dev] [peer-ip-addr]
#
#       [dev]           device to send/rcv heartbeats on
#       [peer-ip-addr]  IP address of peer to send packets to
#
#ucast eth0 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'm trying to change it and I get the following Error: [FAILED]
heartbeat[22579]: 2012/03/21_07:43:04 ERROR: Illegal directive [unicast] in /etc/ha.d/ha.cf
heartbeat[22579]: 2012/03/21_07:43:04 ERROR: Heartbeat not started: configuration error.
heartbeat[22579]: 2012/03/21_07:43:04 ERROR: Configuration error, heartbeat not started.

Comment: @EladDotan I updated my answer. In you case you have to provide two lines:
ucast eth0 IP_of_server01.com
ucast eth0 IP_of_server02.com

Answer (score 0):

To monitor and failover services (and not just boxes), you will need the full Pacemaker/Corosync/Heartbeat setup, not just basic Heartbeat.  If you're using haresources, you're using basic Heartbeat.

Installation from EPEL can be found here:

http://www.clusterlabs.org/wiki/Install#Installing_on_EPEL-5_Compatible_Distributions:_RHEL.2C_CentOS.2C_etc

The ClusterLabs wiki will have [other documentation](http://www.clusterlabs.org/wiki/Documentation) on configuring Pacemaker for specific services.